How can I take legal action on a company who refused to send chat script on customer's request
I would like to know how can I take legal action on a company who refused to share the chat script with customers on request. The customer requested the chat script after chatting with the chat advisor works for the company. If I am not wrong according to GDPR as far I know company is bound to share the chat script to the same customer. I am specifically talking about European law. Can somebody spread some lights on this. Thanks.

Did they give a reason why they wouldn't share it?

"How can I take legal action ...?" ─ through a lawyer.

You have no legal right to a "chat script".
Maybe this is a language issue? A "chat script" is a script the customer service representative uses to do their work. It has nothing to do with you, it contains no data about you. It is their internal work instructions how to talk to customers.
If you requested their "chat script", they have every legal right to tell you to get lost.
Maybe you mean you want the "chat transcript"? The recording of you while speaking to the customer service representative?
That would indeed be covered under the GDPR, given they have one. They are not required to record you in any way. If they didn't, well, then there is obviously nothing to give you.
If they do have personal data on you, like a recording, then they are required to disclose this to you when you file a SAR. Please note that is is their right to have you identify properly to them. They won't send out data based on a random email claiming to be a specific person. If they normally identify you by email (for example online accounts) then it might be enough, but they do have the right to require other means of identification. For example an identity document like a passport or national ID.
The GDPR is not one single law. It's a guideline that is transformed into local laws. So you will need to look up the local law of the juristiction in question and find out who you can report problems to. It should say so in the specific law. A lawyer will be more effective in doing this, but if you feel comfortable, you should be able to do it yourself.
To take Germany as a specific example, they have so called Datenschutzbehörden. Yes, multiple instances of them, for the country itself, for the individual federal states, for instances of government institutions breaking the law and more. You only need to contact them, they will contact their counterparts in other European countries if neccessary, so you only ever have to handle the conversation with a German authority.
